# Creating a search function with multiple search items?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am trying to create a search function for a real estate website. The search must entail the following search fields: area, location, address, property type, bedrooms, baths, and price.

I need to create this search with php (built in a wordpress site) but I am a new to developing with php.

Can someone point me in the right direction or possibly help me get started?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.php.net is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304

I'd say that'd be a good place to start, assuming you're on MySQL (most wordpress are) and you can edit the DB. :)

Comment: I built a custom DB that contains all fields for each listing (what we will be search for).

Comment: Full Text Searching is the way to go then. :)